# Getting error when setting up SSIS with MySql .net connector

Tags: mysql, ssis, mysql-connector

I'm trying to build up an SSIS package by following http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/06/04/howto-connect-to-mysql-in-ssis/. Everything works well when I moved to step #6. When I double click the connection again, I met following error.

**Note**

1. I'm using **VS 2012 & 2010**. Both have the same error.
2. I installed **MySql installer 5.6.26** for Windows https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/. It contains the MySql .Net Connector **6.9.6.0**
3. My machine.config has `DbProviderFactories` added as the bottom
4. I added `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` into my project.

> ===================================
>
> Could not get provider invariant name from the connection type
>   qualifier "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d".
>   You may need to manually edit the 'Qualifier' property of the
>   connection manager if the default one selected is different from what
>   you want. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I narrowed down the error log and it turns out that's a problem caused by SQL Server Compact 3.5. I went to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974247 and followed the instruction to get it fixed.

It's just in my case. I saw some other complains about the same error and I would suggest you check the error details too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .NET Providers\MySQL Data Provider, needs the PublicKeyToken of the .dll to connect MySql, maybe because you copy the source from another machine that has a different PublicKeyToken for the .dll of MySql.

So a workarround is to create a new mysql connection, and then go to properties, copy the Qualifier, and paste it into the properties of the old mysql connection that you want to fix.

Then it should be fixed.